# How can you multiply a value from a dictionary with a number to get a real value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests, dictionary-comprehension

```
store={'Rice':450,'Beans':200,'Egg':40,'Fish':250,'Spag':250}

bill=()
total=()

print('Welcome!!!we sell:',"\n",[store])

while True:
    a=input('What would you like to buy?=')
    b=input('how many of each product do you want?=')
    if a in store:
        bill=store[a]*b
        print('bill=',bill)
    elif a not in store:
        print('Sorry we don\'t have that')
    else:
        total=bill+total
print('Total=',total)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your `if/elif/else` is impossible, because wether `a` is IN the dict, wether it isn't, there is no way you into the `else` so put it in the `if`.
- I'd also added a way to stop the loop by entering `stop` without you won't be able to stop the program and print the final `total`
- move `b` input into the `if`, that isn't necessary to ask for quantity if the product isn't available
- added `int()` conversion on `b`

```
store = {'Rice': 450, 'Beans': 200, 'Egg': 40, 'Fish': 250, 'Spag': 250}
print('Welcome!!!we sell:', "\n", store)
total, bill = 0, 0
while True:
    a = input('What would you like to buy? ("stop" to quit): ')
    print(">" + a + "<")  # For OP debug purpose only, to be removed
    if a == "stop":
        break

    if a in store:
        b = int(input('how many of each product do you want?='))
        bill = store[a] * b
        total += bill
        print(f"Total={total} (+{bill})")
    else:
        print('Sorry we don\'t have that')

print('Total=', total)
```

Comment: Thanks I've seen the mistake but the issue is that even when I input stop,the program cease to break
What could be wrong?

Comment: Do `print(">"+ a +"<")` right after the input method to be sure you only entered "stop" , because that should work

Comment: @MayopoAdeoye ths is pretty clear, put `print(">"+ a +"<")` right before `if a == "stop":` with same indentation